# If I have made a BTC transaction after the fork and haven't claimed my BCH before, have I lost them?

Tags: blockchain-fork

The title sums it up pretty well, I made a transaction with bitcoin core wallet after the fork, but I hadn't claimed those bitcoin cash, can I claim them, or have I lost them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin Cash is an altcoin; things that you do on Bitcoin Cash will not effect your Bitcoin and vice versa.

With Bitcoin Core, you can install it's Bitcoin Cash analogue, [Bitcoin ABC](https://www.bitcoinabc.org/). From there you import your Bitcoin Core wallet into Bitcoin ABC by copying it to the Bitcoin ABC datadir. Then you can spend your Bitcoin Cash normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can claim them.

How to do this? I used a btc.com tool and 12 words seed phrase. With `bitcoin core wallet` procedure will be different, I saw some people recommending `electron cash`.

Comment: Great! Glad to see someone else has been able to claim them, thanks for your answer. Does anyone else know exactly what I should do or knows somewhere where it is explained step by step?